# Magento :: Translate text from javascript files

Tags: javascript, php, magento, translation

Magento uses a system for translating text in the template files using:

`$this->__('text to be translated.');`

or

`Mage::helper('modulename')->__('text to be translated.');`.

This works quite well.
But when I add text to a javascript file I can't use these two methods.

Is there a way I could do a similar thing with the translations for javascript files?

Comment: This is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450294/magento-translate-validation-error-messages#answer-3839423

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento, translate validation error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450294/magento-translate-validation-error-messages)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do it in a template file yourfile.phtml. The JavaScript `js/mage/translate.js` file must be included in your HTML header (Magento does it by default).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Translator.add('You should take care of this confirmation message!','<?php echo Mage::helper('yourmodule')->__('You should take care of this confirmation message!')?>');
</script>
```

Since Magento 1.7, you can add a file jstranslator.xml into your module under the etc/ folder and set the following string like that:

```
<jstranslator>
    <!-- validation.js -->
    <validate-no-html-tags translate="message" module="core">
        <message>HTML tags are not allowed</message>
    </validate-no-html-tags>
    <validate-select translate="message" module="core">
        <message>Please select an option.</message>
    </validate-select>
</jstranslator>
```

Then translate the string as you do it for PHP thanks to the CSV file. This will add the translation to the JavaScript code like the following `var Translator = new Translate(...)`.

Comment: I tried that before but it didn't work.
I'll try it again, jsut to make sure.

Comment: Doesn't work... Unfortunately.
I created a new helper for one of my custom modules in my local folder. And added the Js at the top of my .phtml file. But it just doesn''t work.

Comment: Translator is a javascript variable of Magento. Maybe it's missing. Try in Javascript tag: new Translate({'You should take care of this confirmation message!', '<?php echo Mage::helper('yourmodule')->__('You should take care of this confirmation message!')?>' })

Comment: Check if you have the var Translator in your HTML source code

Comment: Could you provide a code sample of where you want to display the translated string?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450294/magento-translate-validation-error-messages#answer-3839423

Comment: The explanation of what is what in `jstranslator` you can find there https://stackoverflow.com/a/12286636/1335142

Answer (score 5):

Just use the following method in your scripts:

```
Translator.translate('Some phrase');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way for translating JavaScript strings withing .phtml file

```
Translator.add({"To be translated":"<?php echo $this->_('To be translated'); ?>"});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just made the simplest way:

```
let sometext = '<?php echo $this->__('text to be translated.'); ?>' + someVarData;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this is in **js** file:

```
Translator.translate('Some phrase');
```

But to make it work you should define this translation in **phtml**:

```
Translator.add('Some phrase', "<?php echo $this->__('Some phrase'); ?>");
```